# cannot include custom .msg files in python code

Tags: ros, python, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created my own msg files and would now like to use them in python. One line trips me up over and over.

```
from my_package.msg import *
```

I get an error like this:

> ImportError: No module named
> my_package

I do believe I have written the '.msg' files correctly, and I have executed 'catkin_make' successfully on the workspace I'm using for ros development. I also believe I've edited the CMakeLists.txt file correctly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_package)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  map_store
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  MapListEntryList.msg
  MapListElement.msg
#   Message2.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  #my_package
#  MapListEntryList  
#   geometry_msgs#   std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES my_package map_store
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime geometry_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 install(PROGRAMS
   scripts/turtlebot_listen.py
   scripts/turtlebot_map.py
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )
```

The two .msg files are trivial:

```
# MapListEntryList.msg
# num of available maps/ num of maps in list
int8 len

# list of available map_id objects
my_package/MapListElement[] list
```

and

```
# MapListElement.msg

string name
string id
```

I can use rosmsg to look at both messages. If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd be grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121616/cannot-include-custom-.msg-files-in-python-code/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the answer is to `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in your .bashrc file. Though I had run 'catkin_make' successfully I had not sourced this file and I think therefore could not reference the 'my_package' package.

---

Originally posted by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) with karma: 125 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Girts L](https://answers.ros.org/users/3081/girts-l/) on 2018-09-13**:
Yes, I just had the same problem. Before creating the messages I had
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
so ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages was not on the path. After creating the message files and running catkin_make, sourcing devel/setup.bash again fixed the path.

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-12-26**:
Hi  @david.c.liebman  I have the same problem but I didn't understand how to fix it. Shoul d I put source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash in my .bashrc file?